# Adicionar um nó em outro nó filho em um XML

Tags: c#, xmldocument

Estou estruturando um arquivo XML. E preciso Adicionar um outro 'nó' ao meu 'nó filho'.

A função que monto o XML:

```
  private string MontarXML(List<Nota> listaNotas)
    {
        XmlDocument docConfig = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode xmlNode = docConfig.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration, "", "");
        XmlElement rootElement = docConfig.CreateElement("NFSE");
        docConfig.AppendChild(rootElement);

        string cnpj = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < listaNotas.Count; i++)
        {
            cnpj = listaNotas[0].Prestador.CpfCnpj;
            var nota = listaNotas[i];

            XmlElement notaIfo = docConfig.CreateElement("NfseInfo");
            docConfig.DocumentElement.PrependChild(notaIfo);
            docConfig.ChildNodes.Item(0).AppendChild(notaIfo);

            XmlElement prestador = docConfig.CreateElement("Prestador");
            docConfig.DocumentElement.PrependChild(prestador);
            docConfig.ChildNodes.Item(0).AppendChild(prestador);

            XmlElement outrasInformacoes = docConfig.CreateElement("OutrasInformacoes");
            docConfig.DocumentElement.PrependChild(outrasInformacoes);
            docConfig.ChildNodes.Item(0).AppendChild(outrasInformacoes);

            XmlElement valores = docConfig.CreateElement("Valores");
            docConfig.DocumentElement.PrependChild(valores);
            docConfig.ChildNodes.Item(0).AppendChild(valores);

            XmlElement environmentElement = docConfig.CreateElement("Numero");
            XmlText environText = docConfig.CreateTextNode(nota.Numero.ToString());
            environmentElement.AppendChild(environText);
            notaIfo.PrependChild(environmentElement);
            prestador.PrependChild(environmentElement);

            environmentElement = docConfig.CreateElement("Competencia");
            environText = docConfig.CreateTextNode(nota.Emissao.ToString("MM/yyyy"));
            environmentElement.AppendChild(environText);
            notaIfo.PrependChild(environmentElement);
            prestador.PrependChild(environmentElement);
        }

        String path = "~/XML/"+cnpj;

        bool pathExists = Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));
        if (!pathExists)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));
        }
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var x = rnd.Next(9999);
        var data = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

        var notasXML = path + "/" + cnpj + data + x + ".xml";
            docConfig.Save(
                HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(notasXML));
        return notasXML;
    }
```

Só que o resultado não é o esperado, por alguma falha de codificação da minha função.

O resultado de saída:

```
<NFSE>
 <NfseInfo>
  </NfseInfo>
    <Prestador>
     <Competencia>04/2018</Competencia>
   <Numero>1</Numero>
   </Prestador>
  <Valores />
```

Preciso que o .xml se estruture essa forma.

```
<NFSe>
   <NFSeInfo>
     <NotaInfo>
       <Numero>51</Numero>
       <Emissao>23/07/2018</Emissao>
     </NotaInfo>
     <Valores> 
       <ValorCofins>15,63</ValorCofins>
    </valores>
   </NFSeInfo>
</NFSe>
```

Comment: Gostaria de entender o porque dos negativos.

Comment: Você está usando o método `AppendChild()` errado. Você precisa criar um elemento e para criar o filho precisa de fazer o `AppendChild()` no pai.
Por ex: cria o nó `NFse`. Depois crie o nó `NFseInfo` Para adicionar um nó filho ao pai faça: `NFSe.AppendChild(NFseInfo)` e assim por diante

Comment: Não entendi bem. Poderia exemplificar. Preciso adicionar um outro nó, ao nó filho.

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversas maneiras de criar um arquivo XML. Aqui está um exemplo de como você pode criar e iterar os nós de forma parecida com a sua idéia/jeito.

```
        public void CreateDoc()
        {
            XmlNode parent, child;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            parent = doc.CreateElement("NFSe");
            doc.AppendChild(parent);

            child = doc.CreateElement("NFSeInfo");
            parent.AppendChild(child);
            parent = child;

            child = doc.CreateElement("NotaInfo");
            parent.AppendChild(child);
            child = doc.CreateElement("Valores");
            parent.AppendChild(child);

            parent = parent.FirstChild;
            child = doc.CreateElement("Numero");
            child.InnerText = "51";
            parent.AppendChild(child);
            // e assim por diante...
        }
```